# Stub KMS with Sinon

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, sinon, amazon-kms

I'm trying to stub KMS methods, like I've stubbed everything else. I'm using sinon.

```
sandbox.stub(AWS.KMS.prototype, 'decrypt')
    .returns(Promise.resolve("some string"))
```

This throws the error "Cannot stub non-existent property decrypt".

I've seen other posts that recommend using `aws-sdk-mock`, but I want to avoid that. I've already got a lot of AWS-related unit tests, and I don't want to have one set that's implemented differently than others.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution...

First, I'm using the promise type of AWS methods:

`KMS.decrypt(params).promise()`

So to stub this, I'm doing the following:

```
sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()
const mKMS = {
  decrypt: sandbox.stub().returns({
    promise: () => {Promise.resolve({
      Plaintext: "some string",
      CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from("some string", 'utf-8')
    })}
  })
}
sandbox.stub(AWS, 'KMS').callsFake(() => mKMS)
```

Also, I'll admit that I'm still working out exactly what kind of object is returned from that `Promise.resolve()` -- but it's successfully stubbing the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stub.returnsThis()` to stub the chain method call so that you don't need to nest the stubbed objects. It gives you a flattened `mKMS` object.

E.g.

`main.ts`:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export function main() {
  const aws = new AWS.KMS();
  return aws.decrypt().promise();
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```
import { main } from './main';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('62400008', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mKMS = {
      decrypt: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      promise: sinon.stub().resolves({
        Plaintext: 'some string',
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from('some string', 'utf-8'),
      }),
    };
    sinon.stub(AWS, 'KMS').callsFake(() => mKMS);
    const actual = await main();
    expect(actual).to.be.deep.equal({
      Plaintext: 'some string',
      CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from('some string', 'utf-8'),
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mKMS.decrypt);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mKMS.promise);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  62400008
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (9ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 main.ts  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```